# How to get item list from wxpython ListBox

Tags: python, listbox, wxpython, listboxitems

Is there a single method that returns the list of items contained in a wxPython listBox?

I cant seem to find anything anywhere in the documentation or anywhere for that matter. All that I can think to do is to set the selection to all of the items and then get the selected  items, though seems like an  ugly roundabout way of doing something that should be simple.

**Update:**

As pointed out by jeremy the way to do this is with `GetStrings()`

e.g.

`listBoxList = yourListBox.GetStrings()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`wx.ListBox` is derived from `wx.ControlWithitems`.  I think [GetStrings()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxcontrolwithitems.html#wxcontrolwithitemsgetstrings) is what you need.

Comment: +1 Exactly what I wanted -I new there had to be a simple way... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of the strings in the listbox like:

```
[listBox.GetString(i) for i in range(listBox.GetCount())]
```