# Python program gives me range of items instead of most/least frequent item

Tags: python, list, loops, range

I've created a GUI using wxFormBuilder that should allow a user to enter the names of "visitors to a business" into a list and then click one of two buttons to return the most frequent and least frequent visitors to the business. Unfortunately, when I click the button, it gives me the range of visitors, rather than the name of the most/least frequent visitor. I've attached a screenshot of the GUI I've created to help add a little clarity to the issue and have appended my code. Thanks in advance for your help with this.

[image]

Code:

```
import wx
import myLoopGUI

class MyLoopFrame(myLoopGUI.MyFrame1):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        myLoopGUI.MyFrame1.__init__(self, parent)

    def clkAddData(self,parent):
        if len(self.txtAddData.Value) != 0:
            try:
                myname = str(self.txtAddData.Value)
                self.listMyData.Append(str(myname))
            except:
                wx.MessageBox("This has to be a name!")            
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("This can't be empty")




    def clkFindMost(self, parent):
        word_amount = range(self.listMyData.GetCount())
        numberofitems = self.listMyData.GetCount()
        unique_words = []
        for word in word_amount:
                if word not in unique_words:
                    unique_words += [word]
        word_frequencies = []
        for word in unique_words:
            word_frequencies += [float(word_amount.count(word))/len(word_amount)]

        max_index = 0
        frequent_words =[]
        for i in range(len(unique_words)):
            if word_frequencies[i] >= word_frequencies[max_index]:
                max_index = i
                frequent_words += [unique_words[max_index]]
        self.txtResults.Value = str(frequent_words)



myApp = wx.App(False)
myFrame = MyLoopFrame(None)
myFrame.Show()
myApp.MainLoop()
```

@Yep_It's_Me was kind enough to chime in and offer another way forward:

```
import wx
import myLoopGUI
import commands

class MyLoopFrame(myLoopGUI.MyFrame1):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        myLoopGUI.MyFrame1.__init__(self, parent)

    def clkAddData(self,parent):
        if len(self.txtAddData.Value) != 0:
            try:
                myname = str(self.txtAddData.Value)
                self.listMyData.Append(str(myname))
            except:
                wx.MessageBox("This has to be a name!")            
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("This can't be empty")




    def clkFindMost(self, parent):
        self.listMyData = []
        unique_names = set(self.listMyData)
        frequencies = {}
        for name in unique_names:
            if frequencies.get[name]:
                frequencies[name] += 1
            else:
                frequencies[name] = 0

        v = list(frequencies.values())
        k = list(frequencies.keys())
        self.txtResults.Value = k.index(max(v))


    def clkFindLeast(self, parent):
        unique_names = set(self.listMyData)
        frequencies = {}
        for name in unique_names:
            if frequencies.get(name):
                frequencies[name] += 1
            else:
                frequencies[name] = 0

        v = list(frequencies.values())
        k = list(frequencies.keys())
        self.txtResults.Value = k.index(min(v))

myApp = wx.App(False)
myFrame = MyLoopFrame(None)
myFrame.Show()
myApp.MainLoop()
```

But now I'm receiving a Value error:

**ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence**

In relation to this line:

```
**self.txtResults.Value = k.index(max(v))**
```

Never mind! @Yep_It's_Me offered a fantastic solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
range(self.listMyData.getCount())
```

will give a list of integers from `0` to `self.listMyData.getCount()`.

You want to count the occurrences of each unique item in `self.listMyData` yes?

**Update**: From the comments, `self.listMyData` is the textbox, not the list of names, get the list of names from the textbox as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229749/how-to-get-item-list-from-wxpython-listbox). Updated code.

```
# Get the list of names from the textbox
name_list = self.listMyData.GetStrings()
unique_names = set(name_list)
frequencies = {}
for name in unique_names:
    if frequencies.get(name):
        frequencies[name] += 1
    else:
        frequencies[name] = 0
```

Now `frequencies` will be a dict of names, with the value being the frequency of that name in `self.listMyData`

Then you can do:

```
counts = list(frequencies.values())
names = list(frequencies.keys())
max_count_index = counts.index(max(counts))
min_count_index = counts.index(min(counts))
most_frequent = names[max_count_index]
least_frequent = names[min_count_index]
```

Which will assign a list of integers to `counts` which represent the frequency of each name in `names`. Getting the index of both the maximum and minimum in `counts` tells us in index in `names` which has the most frequent and least frequent names, respectively. Then we can access them in the normal way.

Comment: This definitely seems like a step in the right direction, but when I run this code, I keep receiving this error:     

unique_names = set(self.listMyData)
TypeError: 'ListBox' object is not iterable

Comment: and, of course, when i change to set[self.listMyData] i get
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What is `self.listMyData`? Is it a list? or is the the textbox that displays the names in the GUI?

Comment: It's the name of the textbox (wxListBox) that displays the list in the GUI. Would I add .Value at the end of that construction?

Comment: If `.value` gives you the list that is contained within the textbox then yes. `set(self.listMyData.value)` just takes the list and turns it into a set, which cannot have duplicate elements. So it can only take list-like objects as a parameter. `set[self.listMyData]` wouldn't work since you're trying to access `set` as a list, which it is not.

Comment: Let me know if that works for you and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I was still getting the error, so I set self.listMyData = [] above the equation, which seemed to solve the issue. But now I'm getting a max(v) arg is empty error down at the bottom of the code. Thanks a lot for your help on this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, @Yep_It's_Me, the top code now looks like this:    

def clkFindMost(self, parent):
    self.listMyData = []
        unique_names = set(self.listMyData)
        frequencies = {}

Comment: Can you update you're question to how your code is now and what your error is saying?

Comment: I have updated the answer. See if that works for you.